# Inner JOIN performance: can I select only few values?

Tags: php, select, join, inner-join

I have a large dataset that I need to output in a table for study reasons, I work on a local server.
I first wrote this code

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT xxx, yyy, zzz FROM table1 ORDER BY xxx ASC LIMIT 0, 100");
```

which is ok, it takes one instant to output the values.
The problem is i need to join table1 to another table of the same database, so I do this

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT xxx, yyy, zzz FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.yyy=table2.yyy ORDER BY xxx ASC LIMIT 0, 100");
```

and the query stucks forever.

Is there some coding error? I think no, because I did the same query on a smaller database with the same table structure and it worked.

So, I guess the problem is that when I perform the join all the values from table2 are called and my poor local server doesn't manage to finish the query (also, I notice a huge amount of disk space is used, when second query is performed, an I talk about several GB of space).
Is there some way to select only few records from table 2, as I did for table 1? I mean something like `SELECT xxx, yyy, zzz FROM table1` and also `SELECT yyy, www, aaa FROM table2` and join just these values.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: What about not using `ORDER BY` in your query?

Comment: If you first limit the output of both tables to e.g. 100, it could happen that your joined result yields less than 100 tuples, so this could affect the overall result. Have you thought about creating indices on the join columns? Additionally, ordering the query might potentially slow it down.

Comment: This is where using EXPLAIN on your queries might shed some light on how MySQL is executing the query

Comment: Order by slows it down a lot... I didn't know. Thanks everyone.
Now I'm trying to work on the index, as said by sebastian_oe.

Comment: is table1.yyy or table2.yyy indexed/primary key?

Comment: Actually, the problem wasn't what I thought: cutting out order by and also the Limit the query worked just fine and I managed to get the output in few seconds (a very huge table). Thanks to Electrosa and Sebastian_oe for fundamental help.

Answer (score 0):

I think is the field conflict,

try

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT xxx, yyy, zzz FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.yyy=table2.yyy ORDER BY YOUR_TABLE.xxx ASC LIMIT 0, 100");
```